# Multiple data insert in Parse using android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have an application that insert & retrieve data from parse. but i need to insert multiple entry in a single task under one id. I can do that using loop but is there anyway to insert multiple entry at once? For an example: I have an user id "ABC" and this user entry some data like : data-1(abc, Ny, water), data-2(xyz,bristol, air), data-3( qwe, ca, fire). how can i insert all 3 data under ABC id altogether into parse?

```
ParseObject userOrder = new ParseObject("tableName");
    userOrder.put("userId", userId);
    userOrder.put("data",data);
    userOrder.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null){
             //successfully data inserted
            } 
 else {
                    //there is an error in data insertion                }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you find  a way to do this ?

Comment: no... i haven't found any solution yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can do that using saveAllinBackground

```
final List<ParseObject> parseTaskObjects = new ArrayList<>();
for (TaskResponse taskResponse : ((MainApplication)(getApplicationContext())).getTaskResponses()) {
    ParseObject parse_assignment = new ParseObject("TaskResponse");
    parse_assignment.put("TaskID", list.get(((MainApplication) (getApplicationContext())).getTaskResponses().indexOf(taskResponse)));
    parse_assignment.put("AssignmentId", assignment);
    if (taskResponse.getTaskType() == TaskType.LOCATION.ordinal()) {
        parse_assignment.put("LocationResp", getParseGeoPointFromLatLng(taskResponse.getLocationResponse().latitude, taskResponse.getLocationResponse().longitude));
     } else if (taskResponse.getTaskType() == TaskType.PICTURE.ordinal()) {
         ParseFile file = new ParseFile("image.jpg", taskResponse.getPictureResponse());
         file.saveInBackground();
         parse_assignment.put("PicResp", file);
      } else if (taskResponse.getTaskType() == TaskType.TAGS.ordinal()) {
          parse_assignment.put("TagResp", taskResponse.getTagResponse());
      } else if (taskResponse.getTaskType() == TaskType.TEXT.ordinal()) {
          parse_assignment.put("TextResp", taskResponse.getTextResponse());
      } else if (taskResponse.getTaskType() == TaskType.NUMBER.ordinal()) {
          parse_assignment.put("NumResp", taskResponse.getNumberResponse());
      }

      parseTaskObjects.add(parse_assignment);
   }

   ParseObject.saveAllInBackground(parseTaskObjects, new SaveCallback() {
       @Override
       public void done(ParseException e) {
           if (e == null) {
               Toast.makeText(Stint_task.this, "Stint Tasks Completed Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           } else {
               Toast.makeText(Stint_task.this, "Stint Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks... from the  ParseObject.saveAllInBackground(parseTaskObjects, new SaveCallback() of your code has done my job.